# Assembly: Invalid effective address

Tags: assembly

I'm new to assembly (as you can plainly see) and I'm trying to compile the following:

```
hex_charmap db '0123456789ABCDE'
mov   al, [hex_charmap + ax]
```

However I get the following error on line 2:

> error: invalid effective address

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Might be a bit late, but your hex charmap should probably include 'F' too :)

Comment: @lionkor a BIT late?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My assembler's rusty. Can AX really be used as an indexing register?

**Update**:

Just found what I was looking for. **Only BX can be used as an index register!**

See this link for another similar questions and its similar explanation:

[invalid effective address calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809141/invalid-effective-address-calculation)

Comment: Why is it that only `BX` can be used as an index register?

Comment: Essentially, that's how Intel designed their instruction set. Making all the registers equally all-round would have required more circuitry, brought up cost, making the chip slower and less efficient, and so forth. Other processors were designed differently, but not this one.

Comment: @SamHolmes: Encoding limitations.  But SI or DI can also be used in addressing modes, not just BX or BP.  See the linked duplicate: [Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: \[bx\] works, \[cx\] doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866854)