# invalid effective address calculation

Tags: assembly, x86-16, addressing-mode

Please look at the following program, the error is invalid effective address calculation and i have mentioned that line please tell me why its invalid effective address calculation
here is the program

```
[org 0x100]
jmp start


array1: dw 10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
array2: dw 15,10,20,35,40,30,55,50,25,45

start:  mov bx,0
    mov cx,0
loop:   mov ax,[array2+bx]
        cmp ax,[array1+cx]//here is the error invalid effective address calculation 
        jne NextElementOfArray1


NextElementOfArray2:    add bx,2
                        cmp bx,20       
            je end
                        mov cx,0
            jmp loop


NextElementOfArray1:    add cx,2        
                        cmp cx,20       
            je NextElementOfArray2   
            jmp loop
end:    mov ax,0x4c00
    int 0x21
```

Comment: where is cx assigned? you assigned ax and dx. what is the value of cx?

Comment: i have made the correction please check now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
start:  mov bx,0
        mov dx,0 ; <-- did you mean "mov cx, 0" ?
loop:   mov ax,[array2+bx]
        cmp ax,[array1+cx]
```

Edit: If I recall correctly, `cx` register can not be used as an index.

[Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte](http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253666.pdf)

```
Effective Address Mod R/M Value of ModR/M Byte (in Hexadecimal)

[BX+SI]
[BX+DI]
[BP+SI]
[BP+DI]
[SI]
[DI]
[BX]
[BX+SI]+disp8
[BX+DI]+disp8
[BP+SI]+disp8
[BP+DI]+disp8
[SI]+disp8
[DI]+disp8
[BP]+disp8
[BX]+disp8
[BX+SI]+disp16
[BX+DI]+disp16
[BP+SI]+disp16
[BP+DI]+disp16
[SI]+disp16
[DI]+disp16
[BP]+disp16
[BX]+disp16
```

Comment: which register i should use here

Comment: @Zia, I posted a list of valid indexes, from Intel's manual. Don't forget to download it and to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to remember the address specification with the following formula (for TASM):

```
[BX|BP]+[SI|DI]+constant
```

Where | Denotes the OR (meaning that BX and BP can't be in the same address specification).
constant can be a variable or a numeric constant.