# Masm32 on Linux: Why does mov [bx], ax work, but mov [ax], bx (or mov [bl], al) doesn't?

Tags: linux, assembly, masm

when I try

```
mov [ax], bx
```

I get the following error: `invalid effective address`
same goes for `mov [al], bl` or something similar.

if I try

```
mov [bx], ax
```

it works. So what is so special about the lower bytes of `ebx`, and how can I accomplish something along the lines of `mov [al], bl` or just swap the contents of the two bytes in `bx`,`ax`,etc. ?

Thanks in advance for anything helpful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid effective address calculation!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809141/invalid-effective-address-calculation) Short answer: not all registers can be used that way.

Comment: Linux programs will be running in 32 or 64-bit (unless you do something really weird).  Use 32-bit or 64-bit addressing, like `[eax]` is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `[bx]` is called the "register indirect addressing mode". in 16-bit mode the following registers can be used in this manner: `bx`, `bp`, `si` and `di`.

For more information, see [The Register Indirect Addressing Modes](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html#HEADING2-35).

> how can I accomplish something along the lines of `mov [al], bl`

This doesn't quite make sense because it would use the 8-bit value of `al` as an address, and addresses in this case are 16-bit. If you are just trying to move the value of `bl` into `al`, then the square brackets are unnecessary:

```
mov al, bl
```

Comment: In 32-bit and 64-bit assembly, though, [it *is* possible](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html#modrm_byte_32).

Comment: @Tinctorius `mov [al],bl` is **not** a valid instruction in 32-bit or 64-bit x86 assembly any more than in 16-bit x86 assembly. However, `mov [eax],bl` is valid 32-bit instruction and `mov [rax],bl` is a valid x86-64 instruction.

Comment: Very true :) If that's really what OP wants, `movzx ax, al` (or `movzx eax, al`, or `movzx rax, al`) followed by a swap between `ax` and `bx`, and then `mov [bx], al`.

Comment: I'm confused by the reference to Linux. Will Masm run in Linux? Japheth's JWASM should, though...